# What is a collective noun for "a set of policies"?

Tags: single-word-requests, collective-nouns

I'm having trouble find a collective noun (or similar word) that describes a "set or collection of [business] policies" for some documentation I'm writing for my domain of work (without going into specifics, I'm involved in reselling inventory for clients/suppliers).

My initial thought was "contract", but that already has an established meaning in our domain (a contract is an agreement with a supplier).  The word I'm looking for is to describe the set of specific policies tied to an individual piece of inventory (i.e. "return policy", "terms and conditions of use", "pick-up instructions", etc.).

Any other ideas?

Comment: What's wrong with plain ***policies**?* They might as well be singular ***policy*** anyway, if they're all concerned with the same thing.

Comment: They are not policies (plural), the document is the **policy** manual relating to various aspects such as returns, usage, ....

Comment: Using the plural is likely to suggest that you have more than one policy on a given aspect -- that is better avoided.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Even if not the same thing, it's *policy*, the only use of the plural seems to be in the insurance business.

Comment: @Kris: Agreed, but when you say you have a corporate "policy" that's actually embodied in multiple contracts, documents, etc., the implication is *they all form a coherent whole*. At least to the extent that there are no conflicts between them.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I debated "policy" but I get concerned about overusing the word. Part of the problem is that one of the items in the collection is the "return policy" (or cancellation policy, for certain items). Maybe it needs to be shortened to just "Returns" or "Cancellations"? But then how do identify individual items (i.e. the statement "If you cancel your rental within X days, you take Y% penalty" has been considered 1 "cancellation policy", and a single product have can multiple of these items. It's possible that I can change that precedent, but I would need to have an alternative.

Comment: @Kris Broadly speaking, this is the information I'm trying to encompass with the collective noun: (1) Pick-up information/instructions; (2) Return/cancellation policies; (3) Terms and conditions of use/service; (4) Additional fees; (5) Taxes.

Comment: There are two points here: Calling one of the constituents a 'policy' is no bar on calling the whole set a policy (see below). As I already said, (2) would better be *Return/Cancellation Policy* (singular) or just plain *Returns/Cancellations*. We could also use the name *Policy on Returns & Cancellations*, which sounds far better to me (that one is an opinion, though).

Comment: Compare with 'opinion'. Your opinion on various issues constitutes of your opinion on each of the issues, yet it's your opinion (singular) not opinions (that would mean you are ambivalent or undecided). You gather your friends opinions (plural) on an issue or several issues.

Comment: @Kris "Opinion" arguably has alternatives though.  "Your opinion on various issues constitutes of your *view/viewpoint* on each of the issues."  Using "view" instead of "opinion" makes the whole statement much more straightforward/less awkward to understand.  Example using my situation: "The Policy encompasses Policy on Returns & Cancellation, Policy on Pick-up, and Policy on Use."  "Protocol" could be the equivalent of "view" in this example, but I'd at least want a less technically-loaded term if at all possible.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest "guidelines" or "protocol" for the specific applications you have outlined.

Comment: Protocol is pretty good, though possibly a little too technical for this domain (I'm sure at least one of the other software developer would complain).  I'm considering it.